# Traer datos segun ID de un option o de un boton de un listado

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

Buenas comunidad,

De antemano, Gracias por tomarse su tiempo de leer, mi consulta es la siguiente:

Tengo una tabla que contienen unos datos:

[[image: Y un boton para cargar una ventana modal:[img]https://k60.kn]]

Y un boton para cargar una ventana modal:

[image: La cual contiene unos datos, entonces lo que requi]ero es poder traer los datos de acuerdo al ID en el que yo desee:

Este es mi query, pero deberia cambiar de acuerdo al identificador que yo tenga en la fila de mi tabla HTML,

> algo asi como cuando tengo cargado en un Select con Options y cada
>   Option tiene su Id y trae sus datos respecto al ID.

```
[code][color=#000000]
SELECT
pemp.id_puntoEmpresa,
pemp.nombre_punto,
pemp.direccion_punto,
pemp.telefono_punto,
pemp.email_punto,
pemp.descripcion_punto,
empr.id_empresa,
empr.nombre_empresa,
empr.nit,
ppto.id_parametroPunto,
ppto.nombreParametro

FROM puntoempresa pemp

INNER JOIN ciudades cdes
ON cdes.id_ciudad = pemp.id_ciudades_punto

INNER JOIN departamento dpto
ON dpto.id_departamento = cdes.id_departamento

INNER JOIN persona prna
ON prna.id_usuario_punto = pemp.id_puntoEmpresa

INNER JOIN tipodeusuario tusr
ON tusr.id_tipoDeUsuario = prna.id_tipoUsuario

INNER JOIN empresa empr
ON empr.id_empresa = prna.empresa_per

INNER JOIN parametropunto ppto
ON ppto.id_puntoEmpresa = pemp.id_puntoEmpresa

WHERE pemp.id_puntoEmpresa' = '$id_punto'
[/color][/code]
```

Pero el problema es que no se como pasarle una variable a un metodo GET en Angular, y como recibirla en el PHP.

Intenté de esta manera pero me genera error:

```
[code][color=#000000]
  
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

if (count($data) > 0)
  {
     $idPunto        = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $data->id_punto);
 ....... (para luego pasarle la variable a la consulta)
 } 

[/color][/code]
```

Este es mi funcion para obtener los datos de la tabla:

```
[code]
  $scope.importarDependencia = function(idPunto)
  {
    $scope.id_punto = idPunto;
    console.log($scope.id_punto);

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'mainApp/Read/consultarDependencia.php'
      })
      .then(function successCallback(datosDependencias)
      {
        $scope.tableParametro = datosDependencias.data;
        console.log(datosDependencias);

      },function errorCallback(datosDependencias)
      {
        console.log("Error")
      });
  }
  $scope.importarDependencia();
[/code]
```

Muchas Gracias, espero haberme echo entender!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

con `params` puedes enviar parametros en tu `get`

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'mainApp/Read/consultarDependencia.php'
        params: {
         id: idPunto
        }
      })
```

en tu php puedes recuperar los parametros con `$_GET`

```
$_GET["id"]
```

Comment: Hola Jorge, muchisimas gracias, no tenia conocimiento de "params", me acabas de ahorrar mucho tiempo de trabajo y funcionó a la perfección. MIL GRACIAS!